# Entity framework with oracle 11g and dot net 4.0

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, odp.net

I was trying to figure out which version of entity framework and ODP.NET should be used with MVC4 (Dot NET 4.0).

I have Visual Studio 2010 & have created MVC 4 app.

Then I installed [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework)

and

while installing [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/)

I got following error

> Could not install package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
>   12.1.021'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Ve rsion=v4.0', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
>   with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Can some one please guide me on how to install EntityFramework for oracle using Visual Studio 2010.
Thanks!!! Help will be appreciated.